# Keras merge layer warning

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I'm keeping getting this warning:

> lstm.py:119: UserWarning: The `merge` function is deprecated and will be removed after 08/2017. Use instead layers from `keras.layers.merge`, e.g. `add`, `concatenate`, etc.
>     merged_vector = merge([l1, l2], mode=lambda x: (x[0] - x[1])**2, output_shape=lambda x: x[0])
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/layers.py:456: UserWarning: The `Merge` layer is deprecated and will be removed after 08/2017. Use instead layers from `keras.layers.merge`, e.g. `add`, `concatenate`, etc.
>     name=name)

Which is related to the following line of code:

```
merged_vector = merge([l1, l2], mode=lambda x: (x[0] - x[1])**2, output_shape=lambda x: x[0])
```

My model works fine, but how do I implement a custom merge in `Keras 2.0.2`? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering my own question:

```
# Custom Merge
def euclid_dist(v):
    return (v[0] - v[1])**2

def out_shape(shapes):
    return shapes[0]

merged_vector = Lambda(euclid_dist, output_shape=out_shape)([l1, l2])
```